# Many to many relationship in Flask with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I want to create a family tree where the relationships are only godfather and godson. Is this the right way to declare the personn class ?

```py
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

from genealogie.extensions import db

Base = declarative_base()

relationship = db.Table('relationship', Base.metadata,
    Column('godfather', db.Integer, ForeignKey('personn.id'), primary_key=True),
    Column('godson', db.Integer, ForeignKey('personn.id'), primary_key=True))

class Personn(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'personn'

    id = Column('id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = Column('first_name', db.String(255), nullable=False)
    last_name = Column('last_name', db.String(255), nullable=False)
    birthdate = Column('birthdate', db.DateTime, nullable=True)
    promo = Column('promo', db.Integer, nullable=False)
    description = Column('description', db.Text, nullable=True)
    godfather = db.relationship('Personn',
        secondary=relationship,
        primaryjoin=relationship.c.godfather==id,
        secondaryjoin=relationship.c.godson==id,
        backref="godson")
```

Comment: soo ... how does your database cover the possibility of multiple godparents? Or of multiple godchildren?

Comment: With the relationship table